# Checking for invalid characters with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, validation, email

Sorry if the question is pretty basic-I am coming from the design side of web stuff (HTML/CSS) and am new to Javascript. My first two validations are working (checking for empty fields for name and email) but I can't get the error message to show up for the illegal characters check.
Here is the code, I've pieced it together from various 'how to' sources. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function validateForm(){
    var noName=document.forms["myForm"]["sender_name"].value;
    noEmail=document.forms["myForm"]["sender_email"].value;
    illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

    if (noName==null || noName==""){
        alert("Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein");
        return false;
    }

    if (noEmail==null || noEmail==""){
        alert("Bitte geben Sie Ihre Email-Adresse ein");
        return false;
    }

    if (noName.match(illegalChars)){
        alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7L3CQ/2/

Comment: You don't need to escape most characters inside `[]` in a regular expression. You also have an unnecessary extra set of braces in your last `if`, and you're missing the close brace for the function.

Comment: Thank you Barmar. It is part of an php document and it did work just now uploaded to a server, but the error message didn't show up with the other JS messages when testing locally. Thanks for pointing out the syntax errors, I've corrected them now - Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer has already been given in the comment, and also the fiddle. But I thought I would help with a little JS syntax as well:

```
    function validateForm() {
    var noName = document.forms["myForm"]["sender_name"].value;
    var noEmail = document.forms["myForm"]["sender_email"].value;
    var illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/;

    if (!noName) {
        alert("Bitte geben Sie Ihren Namen ein");
        return false;
    }
    if (!noEmail) {
        alert("Bitte geben Sie Ihre Email-Adresse ein");
        return false;
    }

    if (noName.match(illegalChars)) {
        {
            alert("Ungültige Eingabe");
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

There is no need to check for null and "" as they are both falsey value in JS so a simple:

```
if(!noName)
```

This will suffice.

Also when you declare variables at the top you need to remember to use the var statement for each variable or use one var and commas between the declarations:

```
    var//iable declarations 
        noName = document.forms["myForm"]["sender_name"].value,
        noEmail = document.forms["myForm"]["sender_email"].value,
        illegalChars = /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/
    ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L3CQ/3/